# How do I apply a list of argument values to a function in R?

Tags: r, list, apply

Say you have a number of objects in your R environment, such as:

```
a <- 4
b <- 3
c <- 2
aa <- 2
bb <- 6
cc <- 9
```

Now say you would like to remove the objects in your environment that are named with the letters 'a' or 'b'. This can be achieved with

```
rm(list = ls(pattern = "a"))
rm(list = ls(pattern = "b"))
```

However, imagine trying to solve this problem on a much bigger scale where you would like to remove all objects whose values appear in a list such as:

```
custom <- list("a", "b")
```

How do I apply this list as a 'looped' argument to the `ls()` function?

I have experimented with:

```
rm(lapply(custom, function(x) ls(pattern = x)))
```

But this does not seem to do anything.

This feels like quite a common problem,  so I fear there is an answer to this issue elsewhere on stackoverflow. Unfortunately I could not find it.

Comment: suggest editing this question using less easily replicated names, so that people don't inadvertently delete other objects from their environments that have the letter a or b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:** This is a vectorized approach. Paste the `custom` list together using an "or" regex separator (`|`) and pass it to `pattern`.

```
rm(list = ls(pattern = paste(custom, collapse = "|")))
```

**Option 2:** If you still want to use `lapply()`, you would have to include the `envir` argument in both `ls()` and `rm()` since `lapply()` itself forms a local environment.  And you would also want to put `rm()` inside the `lapply()` call.

```
lapply(custom, function(x) {
    e <- .GlobalEnv
    rm(list = ls(pattern = x, envir = e), envir = e)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

can be done with a loop easily enough

```
test.a <- 4
test.b <- 3
test.c <- 2
test.aa <- 2
test.bb <- 6
test.cc <- 9

custom <- c("test.a", "test.b")
for (x in custom) rm(list = ls(pattern = x))
```

NB I added test. to the start of the object names, to avoid messing with peoples environment if they run this code.  We don't wnat to inadvertently delete peoples actual objects named a or b etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `grep` will solve your problem:

```
rm(list=grep("^[ab]$", ls(), value=T))
```

will remove objects a and b, but nothing else.

```
rm(list=grep("^[ab]", ls(), value=T))
```

will remove objects a, aa, b, and bb, but leave c and cc in the environment.